# Error al devolver un array en Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, array, eclipse

Muy buenas comunidad, vengo con un problemita y espero me puedan ayudar. Lo que hace mi programa (o debería hacer) es devolverme el saldo que voy a tener año a año en forma de array. Al ejecutar el main me devuelve el siguiente mensaje: **[D@123a439b**

Por lo que entiendo me está devolviendo una referencia y no el objeto array.

Espero me puedan ayudar

```java
package inversiones;

public class Inversiones {
    private int plazo;
    private int monto;
    private int interes;

    public double[] calcularInversion(double monto, double interes, int plazo) {

        double[] saldo;

        saldo = new double[this.plazo];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.plazo; i++) {
            saldo[i] = (double) (this.monto * Math.pow((1 + this.interes), i));

        }

        return saldo;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inversiones i = new Inversiones();
        System.out.println(i.calcularInversion(1000, 0.24, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: En ningún lado asignas un valor a `this.plazo`, esta variable no es igual que la variable del parámetro. Si quieres usar las variables de clase debes tener un constructor.

Comment: Si devuelves un array, debes recorrer para imprimir los valores de cada posición.

Comment: @Bicho no necesariamente, pero sí, es una posible solución. De igual forma tiene más problemas que ese

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación de tu problema

Tu problema inicia con el uso de la palabra reservada [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html). Esta palabra hace referencia al contexto de la clase. Normalmente se usa para distinguir entre dos variables con el mismo nombre pero en diferente contexto (a esto se le llama [shadowing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-variable-shadowing-in-java)).

Entonces en tu código al hacer uso de ***this*** estás accediendo a tus variables privadas (que no están inicializadas), no a las que enviaste por el método.

También para hacer la impresión tendrías que hacer uso del método [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double%5B%5D)).

## Soluciones

Para resolver tu problema, puedes quitar la palabra reservada ***this*** y por tanto tus variables privadas puesto que nunca son utilizadas

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Investments investments = new Investments();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(investments.calcInvestment(1000, 0.24, 4)));
    }

    private static class Investments {

        public double[] calcInvestment(double amount, double interests, int investment_term) {

            double[] balance;

            balance = new double[investment_term];

            for (int i = 0; i < investment_term; ++i)
                balance[i] = amount * Math.pow((1 + interests), i);

            return balance;

        }
    }

}
```

O también puedes hace uso del constructor y ya no mandar argumentos a tu método

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Investments investments = new Investments(4, 1000, 0.24);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(investments.calcInvestment()));
    }

    private static class Investments {
        private final int investment_term;
        private final double amount;
        private final double interests;

        public Investments(int investment_term, double amount, double interests) {
            this.investment_term = investment_term;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.interests = interests;
        }

        public double[] calcInvestment() {

            double[] balance;

            balance = new double[investment_term];

            for (int i = 0; i < investment_term; ++i)
                balance[i] = amount * Math.pow((1 + interests), i);

            return balance;

        }
    }

}
```